# Including js from raw.github.com

Tags: javascript, git, internet-explorer, github

I have a github.com demo page that is linking to **https://raw.github.com/.../master/.../file.js** so that I don't need to always copy the `.js` file over to the `gh-pages` branch every time it's changed.  This works in every browser except IE which complains:

> SEC7112: Script from https://raw.github.com/cwolves/jQuery-iMask/master/dist/jquery-imask-min.js was blocked due to mime type mismatch

This complaint is coming from the fact that the file is transferred with:

```
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Content-Type: text/plain
```

which I can't change.

Anyone have any ideas how to accomplish this same thing?  Somehow allowing me to link to the file in the `master` branch without having to always push it to the `gh-pages` branch?

Actual page: http://cwolves.github.com/jQuery-iMask/

(Minor update -- I changed the gh-pages in this exact instance to include the .js file, so IE is no longer broken, but would still like any feedback :))

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I can't help you with tricking IE, and I think from that angle what you are looking for is impossible (and discouraged, since that is not the purpose of Github's raw URLs).

However, you can automate committing the changes to `gh-pages` and pushing to make your life easier. You can do it with a `post-commit hook` to update the relevant files in the `gh-pages` branch automatically. I've cooked up such a `post-commit` script that watches for changes to certain files and commits them to another branch:

```
#!/bin/sh

WATCH_BRANCH="master"
WATCH_FILES="jquery-imask-min.js"
DEST_BRANCH="gh-pages"

# bail out if this commit wasn't made in the watched branch
THIS_BRANCH=$(git branch --no-color | sed -e '/^[^*]/d' -e 's/* \(.*\)/\1/');
if [ "$THIS_BRANCH" != "$WATCH_BRANCH" ]; then
  exit 0
fi

# only update if watched files have changed in the latest commit
CHANGED_FILES=$(git show --pretty="format:" --name-only $WATCH_BRANCH)
if $(echo "$CHANGED_FILES" | grep "^$WATCH_FILES$" -q); then
  # checkout destination branch, then
  # checkout latest version of each watched file and add to index
  git checkout -q $DEST_BRANCH
  git pull -q
  SAVEIFS=$IFS
  IFS=$(echo -n "|")
  for file in $WATCH_FILES; do
    git checkout $WATCH_BRANCH -- $file
    git add $file > /dev/null
  done
  IFS=$SAVEIFS
  # commit with a chance to edit the message, then go back to watched branch
  LATEST_COMMIT=$(git rev-parse $WATCH_BRANCH)
  git commit -m "Also including changes from $WATCH_BRANCH's $LATEST_COMMIT"
  git push origin $DEST_BRANCH
  git checkout -q $WATCH_BRANCH
fi
```

Note that this is a general script, though I have specified the config vars at the top for your purposes. `$WATCH_FILES` can be set to a list of files delimited by braces `|` such as `index.html|js/jquery.js`. Paths must be specified relative to the root of the repo.

Let me know if you have any questions, and if the script helps you!

Answer (score 61):

You can try using https://rawgit.com/ service.
Just replace raw.github.com with rawgit.com

**UPDATE**

The Rawgit service (former Rawgithub) has been shutdown.

> RawGit has reached the end of its useful life
>   October 8, 2018
>
> GitHub repositories that served content through RawGit within the last month will continue to be served until at least October of 2019. URLs for other repositories are no longer being served.
>
> If you're currently using RawGit, please stop using it as soon as you can.

Comment: Since in that case you'd already be using a site not affillated with github, you might as well use http://cdnjs.com/

Comment: Thanks, rawgithub is perfect.

Comment: Also take a look at [raw.githack.com](http://raw.githack.com). The idea is same, but it is a plain-nginx solution which means it should work a little bit faster :)

Comment: @vsync it works, you just need to change `https` to `http` for now. I'll update instruction. Support for https is on roadmap

Comment: ho, I haven't noticed that tiny part :) sorry

Comment: https://raw.githack.com now supports https. Just replace `raw.github.com` with `raw.githack.com`

Comment: Now this is `rawgit.com`.

Comment: This was super helpful for loading scripts into JS Bin for experimentation.

Answer (score 7):

Take a look at [raw.githack.com](http://raw.githack.com). The idea of this service is inspired from rawgit.com. I just realized that using a whole framework (node.js + express.js) for such simple thing as requests proxying is overkilling, and made same stuff using nginx only.

Replace "githubusercontent" domain name chunk in your github/gist URL with "githack" and you're done!

Furthermore, it supports [bitbucket.com](http://bitbucket.com) - simply replace whole bitbucket domain with `bb.githack.com`.

Answer (score 6):

Github's raw URLs aren't designed to be a generic web host.  Push that stuff off to proper host, like say pages.github.com.

Comment: Yeah, the problem with that is that it requires extra work every time I make a commit to master to switch to the pages branch & copy files over.  I'm just trying to avoid this since it seems unnecessary

Answer (score 2):

Nowadays theres [jsDelivr](https://www.jsdelivr.com/), its open source, free and fast.
And supports GitHub! https://www.jsdelivr.com/

Furthermore its from trusted people/company.

I say this because I'm not sure we can trust https://raw.githack.com/

Answer (score 0):

I am also trying to achieve this.  However, I cannot seem to get the solution from @shelhamer to work in my codebase.  Below is the updated post-commit hook script that I used to get it working:

```
#!/bin/sh

WATCH_BRANCH="master"
WATCH_FILES="jquery-imask-min.js"
DEST_BRANCH="gh-pages"

# bail out if this commit wasn't made in the watched branch
THIS_BRANCH=$(git branch --no-color | sed -e '/^[^*]/d' -e 's/* \(.*\)/\1/');
if [ "$THIS_BRANCH" != "$WATCH_BRANCH" ]; then
  exit 0
fi

# only update if watched files have changed in the latest commit
CHANGED_FILES=$(git show --pretty="format:" --name-only $WATCH_BRANCH)
if $(echo "$CHANGED_FILES" | grep "^$WATCH_FILES$" -q); then
  # checkout destination branch, then
  # checkout latest version of each watched file and add to index
  git checkout -q $DEST_BRANCH
  git pull -q
  SAVEIFS=$IFS
  IFS=$(echo -n "|")
  for file in $WATCH_FILES; do
    git checkout $WATCH_BRANCH -- $file
    git add $file > /dev/null
  done
  IFS=$SAVEIFS
  # commit with a chance to edit the message, then go back to watched branch
  LATEST_COMMIT=$(git rev-parse $WATCH_BRANCH)
  git commit -m "Also including changes from $WATCH_BRANCH's $LATEST_COMMIT"
  git push origin $DEST_BRANCH
  git checkout -q $WATCH_BRANCH
fi
```

I had to update the use of grep to make the regex successfully match (-P was not an option on the grep implementation included in Git Bash shell for Windows), add a `git pull` and a `git push origin $DEST_BRANCH`. Oh, and I had to add an empty shell of the directories and files in advance (perhaps just the directories would have sufficed?).

Since this is actually doing a push, I think it may be better to switch this script to being a post-receive script instead of post-commit. Otherwise, you could be pushing code to gh-pages that never made it into master [if you choose not to push it].