# Happy validation issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation, coffeescript

I'm using HappyJS for form validation, but can't seem to make it work.

I have some coffeescript like:

```
jQuery ->
  $(document).ready ->
    $("#new_store").isHappy fields:
        "#store_name":
          required: true
          message: "There really needs to be a name here"
```

and some html like:

```
<form id='new_store'>
   <input id="store_name" type="text" />
</form>
```

Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/we6J6/)

Answer (score 1):

#### Try [this updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/we6J6/4), it works for me.

```
$("#new_store").isHappy fields:
  "#store_name":
    required: true
    message: "There really needs to be a name here"
```

The problem with your fiddle seems to be that you're using the raw GitHub URL to hotlink the HappyJS file. Use [RawGit](https://rawgit.com/) instead. Also, [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16262293).